# emacs not working on Mojave

Tags: osx

I just updated to Mojave. I used to use emacs-mac from https://bitbucket.org/mituharu/emacs-mac/ but with Mojave I just get blank window for emacs. I also tried emacs-plus and building on my own both which had the same issue.

The installation from https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/
and emacs in the terminal seems to work fine. But I need dvisvgm support which neither has.

Please let me know if you would need more information.

HELP!

Comment: Hmmm ... Mojave was released to the public a few hours ago ...  What are the chances that anyone has had a chance test Emacs compatibility ... and/or implement fixes ...?  Your best bet would be to open an issue with Mitsuharu Yamamoto  .... since that author is already advertising:  "This provides a native GUI support for Mac OS X 10.6 - macOS 10.14."

Comment: Just curious, how is dvisvgm integrated into the Mituharu san:s version of Emacs? Can it display dvi files in Emacs windows? Is this something for the official Emacs to adapt?

Comment: FWIW, I have been running the Mojave beta for weeks. After installing it, I compiled emacs-mac [from source](https://bitbucket.org/mituharu/emacs-mac) (`git clone https://bitbucket.org/mituharu/emacs-mac.git`), and it worked fine. But then, I am used to this, having compiled emacs on my own “forever”. It's one of very few software packages I regularly compile myself.

Comment: Alan Third pushed a commit to the master branch of vanilla Emacs on 09/28/2018:  7946445962372c4255180af45cb7c857f1b0b5fa .  I don't have a computer running Mojave, but anyone wanting to give the new patch a try might want to check out the current master branch.

Comment: @Lindydancer I am not sure how it is integrated. I do know that it can display svg (in particular LaTeX equations) with a very nice resolution.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen I did a fresh installation of mituharu's version from brew and now everything works ok. Still not sure what the issue was.

Comment: Glad you got it to work. This kind of thing is not too unusual when upgrading an OS; it's probably not worth your time to try to get to the bottom of it. BTW, in the interest of housekeeping: If you add a brief answer, saying how you got around the problem, and then accept that answer, this question won't hang around on the site forever as an unanswered question.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with `emacs-app` from Macports: https://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=emacs-app   However, it works fine when launched in the terminal (`-nw`).

Comment: The issue persists for me after compiling from source with these instructions: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsForMacOS#toc8

Comment: I no longer have the issue.  I compiled from `master` rather than `emacs-26.1` and used these instructions: https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/nextstep/INSTALL

Comment: Macports bug report: https://trac.macports.org/ticket/57217

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a fresh installation of mituharu's version (https://bitbucket.org/mituharu/emacs-mac/) using brew and now everything works. I had to remove the older version of emacs that I had before starting the installation.